# Generic functions for two classes or structs

Tags: generics, swift

In the project I'm working on, I have two different classes, `Array` and `Matrix`. I want to apply functions implement `Array -> Array` or `Matrix -> Matrix` on these classes.

I currently have

```
func f(x: Array) -> Array{
    return x+1 // generic but is not always this simple
}
func f(x: Matrix) -> Matrix{
    return x+1
}
```

How do I make one function that accepts both classes? I've seen examples that rely on Equatable and other built in protocols, but I only want to use these two classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
func f<T>(x: T) -> T {
    return x + 1
}
```

Comment: I have, but I get compiler errors about `T is not convertible to Matrix` or flip flop.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's because the + operation for the Matrix is not like what the compiler is expecting. (I'm still learning this, too.)

Comment: Yup, a simple `return x` worked. When I try to access specific members of my class, I get the `T does not have a member named <member>`.

Comment: Add a "PlusOne" member to both and use that rather than "+ 1"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a generic function, like the one Gary Makin describes, but one that gives the compiler a bit more information about what's being passed in. What you'll want to do is define a protocol that describes the class members/methods/operators that you'll use in your function, then extend both `Array` and `Matrix` to conform to that protocol. Lastly you add that protocol as a constraint on the generic function, and the compiler will understand that only types that conform to that protocol (which Array and Matrix now do) can be used with that function, and everything will work.

Here's an example with two simple custom classes, MyTypeOne and MyTypeTwo. They each have a private instance variable `counter` (defined in one as an `Int` and the other as a `Double`) and an `incrementBy` method that takes an `Int` and increments the internal counter. Not very useful, but they'll help illustrate the points above:

```
struct MyTypeOne {
    var counter: Int = 0
    mutating func incrementBy(amt: Int) {
        counter += amt
    }
}
struct MyTypeTwo {
    var counter: Double = 0.0
    mutating func incrementBy(amt: Int) {
        counter += Double(amt)
    }
}
```

I have a function `f()` that I'd like to be able to call using either type -- I'll implement this as a generic:

```
func f<T>(var x: T) -> T {
    x.incrementBy(1)
    return x
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler complains that `'T' does not have a member named 'incrementBy'`. Protocols to the rescue!

```
protocol MyIncrementable {
    mutating func incrementBy(amt: Int)
}

extension MyTypeOne : MyIncrementable { }
extension MyTypeTwo : MyIncrementable { }
```

The extensions to `MyTypeOne` and `MyTypeTwo` are empty because they already implemented the protocol -- those extensions just declare that implementation to the compiler. Finally we're ready to update our generic function with the protocol restraint:

```
func f<T: MyIncrementable>(var x: T) -> T {
    x.incrementBy(1)
    return x
}
```

Hope this helps!